# SQLException was unhandled, Dataset -Table Adapter

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have the following stored procedure and I'm calling it from my Windows Forms application DataSet like this:

```
  Me.TransactionTableAdapter.spPaymentApply(130, iAmount, Now)
```

Although I provide the CustomerID, (and stepping in the code to see if it's actually there - and it is) I get the following error during execution:
Procedure or function 'PaymentApply' expects parameter '@CustomerID', which was not supplied.

Here is my SP:

```
USE [dbPB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PaymentApply]    Script Date: 05/30/2013 18:34:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PaymentApply]
   @CustomerID int,
   @Amount int,
   @AsOfDate datetime
AS
WITH Totals AS (
   SELECT
      T.*,
      RunningTotal =
         Coalesce (
            (SELECT Sum(S.Buyin - Coalesce(S.CreditPaid, 0))
            FROM [Transaction] S
            WHERE
               T.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
               AND S.Type = 'Credit'
               AND S.Buyin > Coalesce(T.CreditPaid, 0)
               AND (
                  T.Starttime > S.Starttime
                  OR (
                     T.Starttime = S.Starttime
                     AND T.TransactionID > S.TransactionID
                  )
               )
            ),
        0)
   FROM
      [Transaction] T
   WHERE
      CustomerID = @CustomerID
      AND T.Type = 'Credit'
      AND T.Buyin > Coalesce(T.CreditPaid, 0)
)
UPDATE T
SET
   T.EndTime = P.EndTime,
   T.CreditPaid = Coalesce(T.CreditPaid, 0) + P.CreditPaid
FROM
   Totals T
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1
         V.*
      FROM
         (VALUES
            (T.Buyin - Coalesce(T.CreditPaid, 0), @AsOfDate),
            (@Amount - RunningTotal, NULL)
         ) V (CreditPaid, EndTime)
      ORDER BY
         V.CreditPaid,
         V.EndTime DESC
   ) P
WHERE
   T.RunningTotal <= @Amount
   AND @Amount > 0;
;
```

VB Code:

```
Private Sub btnTransProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTransProcess.Click
        Dim iAmount As Integer
        Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(Me.cboCustomerName.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
        Dim SelCustId As Integer
        SelCustId = drv.Item("CustomerID")
        Try
            iAmount = CType(txtCreditPayment.Text, Integer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Credit Payment Amount!", "Invalid Amount", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End Try
        MsgBox(SelCustId)
        Me.TransactionTableAdapter.spPaymentApply(130, iAmount, Now)
        '
        'Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        'command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 123)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happened ?

You didn't provide the parameter.

### But.. I double-checked...

Maybe you're not calling it the right way ?
Have you tried something like this :

```
  Dim queryString As String = "exec PaymentApply" 

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnStrg)
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 123)
        // ... same for other non-nullable parameters
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    End Using

End Try
```

### Why should I do this ?

When you call your Stored Procedure from you code, you don't provide the `@CustomerID int` parameter.

Since the parameter is not `nullable` it expects a value and will not go any further until you give it one.

If you want it to be nullable you can set a default value to it. This way he will take this value if you don't provide a new one. Exemple :

**From your code, you pass a parameter like this :**

```
someCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 123)
```

**If you want your parameter to be nullable, do something like this in SQL**

```
@CustomerID int = 123
```

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why I have to reopen the connection etc to perform the execution of the SP. Isn't there a way to modify my code to execude it like I have it above?

Comment: `sn't there a way to modify my code to execude it like I have it above?` There is only one line. Can you provide the whole block ? Maybe I could look at it. Also have you tried my approach ?

Comment: I redid everything and now it works. I'm not sure why! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a Table Adapter instead of a Command Object.

see: [Table Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
and  [TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6s413yfa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Your call to `Me.TransactionTableAdapter.spPaymentApply(130, iAmount, Now)` looks like it should provide 130 as the CustomerID- but if the code does not compile/work properly, perhaps you should use the configuration wizard.

Or, consider the use of a command object instead.  The use of both is outlined here:

[How to: Create and Execute an SQL Statement that Returns No Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0k7hxwz6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the configuration wizard which does not return any value.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the CommandType, and other options properly?  It seems to be treating your function as the other over loaded parameter stored procedure which includes the table name as the first object instead of a parameter.